# Combining 100's of mp4s without running out of ram. In order

Tags: python, mp4, moviepy, natsort

I have some code that is great for doing small numbers of mp4s, but at the 100th one I start to run out of ram. I know you can sequentially write CSV files, I am just not sure how to do that for mp4s. Here is the code I have:`11

This solution works:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import os
from natsort import natsorted

L = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/to/the/files"):
#files.sort()
files = natsorted(files)
for file in files:
    if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.mp4':
        filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
        video = VideoFileClip(filePath)
        L.append(video)

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(L)
final_clip.to_videofile("output.mp4", fps=24, remove_temp=False)`
```

The code above is what I tried, I expected a smooth result on first glance, though it worked perfect on a test batch it could not handle the main batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be appending the *contents*
of a large number of video files to a `list`.
Yet you report that available RAM is much
less than total size of those files.
So don't accumulate the result in memory.

Follow one of these approaches:

### keep an open file descriptor

```
        with open("combined_video.mp4", "wb") as fout:
            for file in files:
                ...
                video = ...
                fout.write(video)
```

Or perhaps it is `fout.write(video.data)`
or `video.write_segment(fout)` -- I don't
know about the video I/O library you're using.

The point is that the somewhat large `video`
object is *re-assigned* each time, so it
does not grow without bound, unlike your list `L`.

### append to existing file

We can nest in the other order, if that's more convenient.

```
        for file in files:
            with open("combined_video.mp4", "ab") as fout:
                ...
                video = ...
                fout.write(video)
```

Here we're doing binary append.
Repeated open / close is slighty less efficient.
But it has the advantage of letting you
do a run with four input files,
then python exits,
then later you do a run with pair of new files
and you'll still find the expected half a dozen
files in the combined output.

Comment: You my good sir are a saint, often the simplest solution is the best.

Comment: *"I don't know what video I/O library you're using"* - Isn't it `moviepy`, which they imported and tagged?

Comment: @Dray So this works? Simply concatenating the files? Pretty surprising (though I don't know the format).

Comment: Actually it didn't ,   `File "merger.py", line 17, in <module>
    fout.write(video)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'VideoFileClip' but it will be fine

Comment: It was a simple fix though. Ill post finished code later

Comment: Good god though, it's slow. I'm just processing 1000 250mb-500mb files. Ideas anyone, already disabled audio, tried screwing with the thread parameter.

Comment: Though I do have a batch of 240 files that together add up to about 60 gigs worth... This sucks

Comment: Eh, "rewrote" everything in ffmpeg it just processed 60 gigs in less than an hour